Compute $\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)} \frac{\sin(x)+\cos(y)}{\cos(x)-\sin(y)}=1$ with the sandwich theorem?
I have that the function:
$$f(x,y)=\frac{\sin(x)+\cos(y)}{\cos(x)-\sin(y)}$$
is continuous in $(0,0)$, therefore it is clear that:
$$\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)} \frac{\sin(x)+\cos(y)}{\cos(x)-\sin(y)}=1$$
But, I want to prove it using the sandwich theorem.
In particular, I have to find two functions $g(x,y),h(x,y)$ such that $g(x,y)\leq f(x,y)\leq h(x,y)$ with:
$$\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}g(x,y)=\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)} h(x,y)=1$$
I don't know how to find those functions, any suggestions?

Have you tried using the Taylor series of sin and cos? I think this could give you the bounds you are looking for. Maybe one the bounds.

Yes, I thought about it but I don't think it's correct to expand sin and cos separately given that the function is made up of two variables and they tend to zero independently, or am I wrong?

Try first replacing just one of the terms with its Taylor series and take a look at what happens to the Taylor Series terms as x (or y) tends to 0.

I don't understand how this gives me the functions I'm looking for... can you explain better?

I think you might be able to eliminate some of the Taylor series terms to get a function that will act as a bound but keep its limit at 0 to be 1 (let's say, replace only cos(y) and get rid of all the positive terms to get a lower bound or something with that flavor)

As you already know the limit, you can take $g = h = f$.
